# Video lags in VLC (Raspbian Buster) in Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, video, vlc, raspbian-buster

I installed a fresh image of Raspbian Buster in my Raspberry Pi 2.

When I run the Big Buck Bunny video in VLC (both in full screen and window mode), the video lags.As far as I can remember, this did not happen in Stretch.

However, when I play it from OMXPlayer it does not lag anymore.

How to solve this issue?